# Simplifying an Expression in Python

Tags: python, string, iteration, expression

I feel there must be a simpler/cleaner/faster (choose one or more) way to write this expression...

take a BigString = "This is a long sentence about a red cat named dude."

and LittleStringList = [ "red dog", "red cat", "red mouse" ]

I effectively want a function/expression that returns true when one of LittleStringList is in BigString. I wrote it like this:

```
def listcontains(list, big):
    contains = False
    for string in list:
        if string in big:
            contains = True
        else:
            pass
    return contains
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

edit: Fixed a small error!

Comment: Just a sidenote, but it makes the code a lot more readable if you use proper variable names... call the string something like `s`, and if possible don't use `list` (even python allows this) since that is the name of the built-in type (eg: try `list([1,2,3])`.. )

Comment: of course, sorry. Just wrote up that little example real quick to showcase the concept! Will avoid that more diligently in the future.

Comment: Just a sidenote, but it makes the code a lot more readable if you indent the code samples correctly.  It helps of the `BigString` and `LittleStringList` examples are shown as either code blocks or in a proper code font (using `)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`any([s in BigString for s in LittleStringList])`

or even better using a generator expression - as pointed out by @GWW:

`any(s in BigString for s in LittleStringList)`

Comment: You can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension

Comment: @mhyfritz: Don't need the additional parentheses if the generator expression is the only parameter.

Comment: @JAB and @unbeli: yeah, I never was quite sure about this, so I always added the extra parens to be on the safe side ;) But now, I finally took the opportunity to [read up on the details](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note the possibly big difference in the performance of the first and the second way of doing it, particularly as LittleStringList grows large. When `any` is invoked with a generator it will only iterate until the expression returns True, and then return at once.

Comment: I have to give you extra props and thanks.. my scripts do so many iterations of this basic statement, and with using the any statement instead of my looped if statement the speed increase is just plain lovely.

Answer (score 3):

use any():

```
>>> BigString = "This is a long sentence about a red cat named dude."
>>> LittleStringList = [ "red dog", "red cat", "red mouse" ]
>>> any([str in BigString for str in LittleStringList])
True

>>> BigString = "This is a long sentence about a red bear named dude."
>>> any([str in BigString for str in LittleStringList])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `if string in big`?
Maybe then try:

```
def listcontains(list, big):
    return any([string in big for string in list])
```

Or a version with a generator:

```
def listcontains(list, big):
    def gen():
        for s in list:
            yield s in big
    return any(gen())
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to go thru whole list, return on first match
2. Do not use `string` as variable name, it is a module, `str` is a type, better word would be `word`.
3. Do not use `list` as variable name
4. You are looping on `list` and checking again in `list`, instead of big

so

```
def listcontains(words, big):
    for word in words:
        if word in big:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten it a little you could instead write:

```
def listcontains(list, big):
    for s in list:
        if s in big:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

`any(filter(lambda x: x in BigString, LittleStringList))`

filter will return a list with LittleStringList words inside BigString and any will return true if filter returns a list with some occurence